# English expression for strung together equalities or inequalities (i.e. $a = \dots = z$ or $a < \dots < z$)? German: "(Un-)Gleichungskette"

Tags: soft-question, terminology, translation-request, mathematical-german

Is there a standard expression for strung together equalities/inequalities in English?

What I mean is $a = b = \cdots = z$ or $a < b < \cdots< z$.

In German, I find the words *Gleichungskette* (equality chain) and *Ungleichungskette* (inequality chain) useful when talking and writing about math. In English, do we just refer to the whole thing as "the equality"/"the inequality" when referring to the whole chain?

Possibilities:

- equality chain
- chain of equalities
- equality string
- string of equalities
- others?

Comment: According to this link (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114746/correct-phrase-for-chain-of-equations), the correct term would be $\textbf{continued equality}$, also I have seen the term $\textbf{chain of equalities}$ before, but I don't know if it is standard.

Comment: I would say that "chain" is pretty much used in this context.

Comment: Yes, I have also heard "chain" more often. In the link i posted there is also a comment (by Peter Shor) showing that the term "chain of equalities" is used far more often than "continued equality", especially in more recent times. Link: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chain+of+equalities%2Ccontinued+equality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchain%20of%20equalities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinued%20equality%3B%2Cc0 , this leads me to believe that "continued equality" might be outdated.

Comment: if we are going to have name for non common cases, then at least one can be systematic e.g. poly-equality, poly-inequality. but either of the cases is not common enough to warrant a specific name, for the equality case one can say the following  relation holds, for the inequality it is nothing than a strictly monic relation/sequence .

Comment: @jimjim, what do you mean by non-common cases? Something like $b > a < c$? The cases $a_1 < \cdots < a_N$ or $a_1 = \cdots = a_N$ show up a lot (at least in analysis, probability theory, measure theory). In German, you can use the "-kette" construction even more broadly (e.g. "Inklusionskette" for $A_1 \subset \cdots \subset A_N$ or "Äquivalenzkette" for $A_n \sim \cdots \sim A_N$), so it shows up in even more areas. But I was asking more about current standards, though I like the "poly-" suggestion to make this more broadly applicable.

Comment: @zxmkn : by non common cases I meant $a_k=a_{k=1}=\cdots=a_n$ is not something that we see very often, one can just call that variables having an equality relation. I love your Inklusionskette example, English has a habit of borrowing words and from now on, that would be my goto "English" word for that relation, thank you for fantastic example, I think even in English it is acceptable to use those German words as if they were English words. Maybe adding postfix kette to english words or
meta/super prefixes seems acceptable, e.g. meta/super (in)equality,meta subsets, meta/super equivalence

Comment: interestingly, notation for chain of values,the bra-ket notation might be already using that idea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation